# C# - Do I have to have a new namespace when defining a new class?

Tags: c#

I recently completed an introduction to C# online class at my local community college. In the final exam, there was a multiple choice question:

> Q: Which of the following is true regarding classes that do not contain a Main method?
> A. They are written and compiled exactly the same as classes that do contain a Main method.
> B. They are written exactly the same as other classes, but they are compiled into a netmodule.
> C. When they are written, they must define a new namespace, but they are compiled the same as other classes.
> D. When they are written, they must define a new namespace and they must be compiled into a netmodule.

I chose B but the correct answer from the instructor was D. Can someone help me understand why? I knew I could create a new class with the same namespace used by the one that contains Main(). That was why I chose B.

Comment: technically you don't need to define a namespace at all, if so it will be in global:: namespace. I don't even know what `netmodule` means.

Comment: Did you ask your instructor why D rather than B? Did you show them your code where you reused the same namespace?

Comment: @Crowcoder https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/junfeng/netmodule-vs-assembly

Comment: Your instructor is just flat out wrong.

Comment: A C# class does not require any namespace. No clue what he's talking about with the *netmodule*. Get your money back for the class.

Comment: @mjwills thanks, I looked it up. That's interesting and the second thing I learned todayabout .NET today that I'm surprised I never came across.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. The instructor didn't allow us to use IDE. Everything was done from the command prompt. The netmodule he referred to comes from the command line option /t. For example, using csc /t:module MyNewClass.cs to compile a module, then csc MyMainClass.cs /addmodule:MyNewClass.netmodule to compile/link the whole thing. I couldn't reach the instructor for comment.